# Moq - Correct setup for mocking generic method

Tags: c#, generics, moq

I am trying to mock a generic method and it doesn't work as expected.

I have this service definition

```
public interface ICommandHandlerFactory {
    ICommandHandler<T> GetHandler<T>() where T : ICommand;
}
```

and this Moq setup

```
var handler = new TestCommandHandler();
var handlerFactory = Mock.Of<ICommandHandlerFactory>(o => 
     o.GetHandler<TestCommand>() == handler);
```

If I call `GetHandler` method on the mock with the specific type e.g. `GetHandler<TestCommand>` everything is working as expected and it returns instance of the `TestCommandHandler` class.

But if the mock is injected to another generic class

```
public class CommandBus {
    private ICommandHandlerFactory _handlerFactory;

    public ICommandHandler GetHandler<T>(T command) where T : ICommand {
        return _handlerFactory.GetHandler<T>();
    }
}
```

the following piece of code return `null`

```
var command = new TestCommand();
return commandBus.GetHandler(command);
```

How should I setup Moq to return correct handler even in this case?

Comment: Maybe this question can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072429/mocking-generic-methods-in-moq-without-specifying-t/58640455#58640455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code works, there was a problem in a helper method that initializes `TestCommand` class and that isn't included in the question.

Commands were casted to their base interface (`ICommand`) when initialized. The mock was setup to return handler for `TestCommand` type but is was called with `ICommand` type - that's why it returned `null`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var handler = new TestCommandHandler();
Mock<ICommandHandlerFactory> handlerFactory = new Mock<ICommandHandlerFactory>();
handlerFactory.Setup(x => x.GetHandler<TestCommand>()).Returns(handler);

Mock<CommandBus> commandBus = new Mock<CommandBus>();
commandBus.Setup(x => x.GetHandler<TestCommand>(It.IsAny<TestCommand>())).Returns(handler);
```

Comment: No I didn't because I am trying to test my CommandBus implementation, so I can't mock it.