# How to execute a generic func that is passed as a parameter to a mocked service

Tags: c#, moq

I have a service that is implemented in a separate library and is taking a `Func<T>` as a parameter of a function.

When mocking the service I still need my `Func<T>` to be run.

How do I setup the mock object for this?

I have created the following code example to demonstrate the problem:

```
// This is the service that is in a different library and I want to mock
public interface IServiceToMock
{
    T ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<T> func);
}

public class ServiceToMock : IServiceToMock
{
    public T ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<T> funcToBeExecuted)
    {
        // does some more logic that I don't want to test
        return funcToBeExecuted();
    }
}
```

This is the consumer of the service

```
public class ServiceConsumer
{
    private readonly IServiceToMock service;

    public ServiceConsumer(IServiceToMock service) => this.service = service;

    public async Task Consume()
    {
        await service.ExecuteAsync(async () => await ConsumeInteger(1));
        await service.ExecuteAsync(async () => await ConsumeString("String"));
    }

    // This is the method that I want to be triggered when the Consume() is called
    private async Task ConsumeInteger(int number)
    {
        await new Task<int>(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            return number;
        });
    }

    // This is the method that I want to be triggered when the Consume() is called
    private async Task ConsumeString(string str)
    {
        await new Task<string>(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            return str;
        });
    }
}
```

This is the test I have so far

```
public class TestServiceConsumer
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var moqLibraryService = new Mock<IServiceToMock>();
        // How can I set up the mock to have the Console 
        moqLibraryService.Setup(ms => ms.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<Func<T>>())).Returns(T());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Can you use `Callback()`?

Comment: The problems is that that you can't mock a generic Funct<T> returns. so the last line from the test does not work.

To bypass this a created a stub from IServiceToMock that is calling Func<T> and  not doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this:

```
var moqLibraryService = new Mock<IServiceToMock>();

moqLibraryService.Setup(ms => ms.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<Func<int>>()))
  .Returns( (Func<int> f) => f() );
moqLibraryService.Setup(ms => ms.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<Func<string>>()))
  .Returns( (Func<string> f) => f() );
```

It uses an overload of `Returns` which takes in a `valueFunction` rather than just a `value`. Each time the mocking is done, that anonymous function `(Func<int> f) => f()` will be evaluated again. Here `f` is the it-is-any argument passed to Moq.

Maybe it is harder to do if you do not want to mention the types (here `int`, `string`) explicitly. That would be related to the thread [Mocking generic methods in Moq without specifying T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072429/).

Comment: That is a good idea, but the acttually service is a bit more so the simple way to do to 
 use a stub.