# Mock behavior loose for single method or generic It.IsAny

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an abstract class `Shape` and a couple of classes inheriting from it (`Square`, `Rectangle`, `Triangle`, `Circle`, ...). I also have an `AreaCalculator` class, which  contains a method named `CalculateAreasByShape()`. This method calls a series of `CalculateShapeAreas<TShape>(List<TShape> shapes)` methods for each `Shape` type.

Now, in my unit tests, I have the following code:

```
...
var areaMock = new Mock<AreaCalculator>(MockBehavior.Strict);
areaMock.Setup(m => m.CalculateAreasByShape()).Returns(new Dictionary<Type, decimal>());
var canvas = new DemoCanvas(shapes, perimeterMock.Object, areaMock.object);
var result = canvas.RunShapeCalculations();
...
```

This code fails on the fact, that `MockBehavior` is set to `Strict` and there is no setup for the `CalculateShapeAreas<TShape>()` methods. Now, I know I could run a setup for each of the Shape types, e.g.:

```
areaMock.Setup(m => m.CalculateShapeAreas<Triangle>(It.IsAny<List<Triangle>>())).Returns(default(decimal));
```

But this will create a lot of duplicate code. I wonder whether we can use the fact that all shapes inherit from the same base class. I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
areaMock.Setup(m => m.CalculateShapeAreas<Shape>(It.IsAny<List<Shape>>())).Returns(default(decimal));
```

Alternatively, is it possible to set `MockBehavior.Loose` on a single generic method (meaning, it would not check the actual type)?

Comment: Why don't you mock the Interface instead of the class? Like; `new Mock<IAreaCalculator>`?

Comment: Because later in the test I am also asserting number of calls of different methods within the `AreaCalculator`, which call each other. I skipped some of the setups in order to avoid unnecessary code in my question.

Comment: If this is a Unit test (and not an integration test) and its purpose is to test `canvas.RunShapeCalculations()` then you can mock every combination via Interface. This unit test does not need to know anything going on in `CalculateAreasByShape`, it is only related to the result that you can mock as you like. Eventhough, in  `CalculateAreasByShape` unit test methods, all of the generic methods  gonna need to be mocked

Comment: As I mentioned, I have presented only snippets from the actual code. The whole setup of mocks is in a separate `Arrange` method, which is called in individual unit tests. Some check exceptions, others method results, etc. There are tests also for the `CalculateShapeAreas` method. I just wanted to find a shorter way to mock a generic method for each type which is tested. If it is not possible, please add an answer that it is not possible.

Comment: AFAIK, you need to get rid of `MockBehavior.Strict` to be able to do that and then the class should be marked as virtual. I have had concerned about the simplicity of your codebase that's why asked for an Interface. Happy coding.

Comment: Allright, thank you. I wanted to avoid possible obscure test results with `MockBehavior.Strict`, but I guess I will have to decide whether it is really necessary.

Comment: Could you in your interface use the `IEnumerable` instead of the `List`?

Comment: Similar to the problem described in [Mocking generic methods in Moq without specifying T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072429/). Just like Moq has the `It.IsAny<>` magic for usual parameters, it would be nice if it has `Moq.AnyType` for type parameters. Then you could do, `mock.Setup(pa => pa.Reserve<Moq.AnyType>()).Returns(...)`, for example. And in your example, `areaMock.Setup(m => m.CalculateShapeAreas<Moq.AnyType>(It.IsAny<List<Moq.AnyType>>())).Returns(default(decimal));` where in fact the first `Moq.AnyType` could be inferred. But what if the type needs _constraints_?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen it will be eventually https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It.IsAny` for open generic support is not yet present in the **`moq`**(release 4.12.0). Eventually there are some plans to introduce this, take a look [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/343)

---

I think problem you are facing is because you are using `List<T>` as an input parameter. As you might notice `List<T>` is not covariant.

*What that mean?*

```
List<Shape> shapeList;
IEnumerable<Shape> shapeEnumerable;
var triag = new List<Triangle>();

shapeList = triag; // NOT ALLOWED
shapeEnumerable = triag; // ALLOWED
```

The same makes problem while mocking. One solution could be to change `interface` and instead of passing `List<T>` pass `IEnumerable<out T>`, or as @JeppeStigNielsen pointed out `IReadOnlyList<out T>`. In fact any covariant in `T` interface which is implemented by `List<T>` could be used.

```
areaMock
    .Setup(m => m.CalculateShapeAreas<Shape>(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Shape>>()))
    .Returns(default(decimal));
```

Comment: If needed, you can also use `IReadOnlyList<out T>` which is also covariant in `T`. Both a `T[]` and a `List<T>` implement it. With that, you can use stuff like the `shapes.Count` property and the `get` part of the indexer, `shapes[i]`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen indeed, tnx

Comment: In this case, your link to https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/343 is the correct answer for me. Please, could you add it to your post, as well?