# Mocking a complex generic method using Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I have the following interface

```
public interface Itf {
   bool M();
   bool Method<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> x);
}
```

I cannot figure out how to mock the method Method (using Moq)

```
var mck = new Mock<Itf>();
mck.Setup(o => o.M()).Callback(() => { }); //Ok
mck.Setup(o => o.Method(???)).Callback(x => {...}); //What should I replace ??? with?
```

**DESIRED BEHAVIOUR**

What I would like to achieve is to have my callback called whenever Method is called. This is what I tried :

```
mck.Setup(o => o.Method(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DocumentCollectionModel, bool>>>()))).Callback<Expression<Func<DocumentCollectionModel, bool>>>(x => {...}); //OK

mck.Setup(o => o.Method(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<It.IsAnyType, bool>>>()))).Callback<Expression<Func<It.IsAnyType, bool>>>(x => {...}); //Callack not called

mck.Setup(o => o.Method(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<It.IsSubtype<object>, bool>>>()))).Callback<Expression<Func<It.IsSubtype<object>, bool>>>(x => {...}); //Callack not called
```

While the first example works, if possible I would like to have it generic, like the second or third, otherwise I have to repeat the mock for every specific type.

Comment: See [Mocking generic methods in Moq without specifying T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072429/mocking-generic-methods-in-moq-without-specifying-t). It seems to be similar to your problem.

Comment: I've never worked with moq but from a quick read of the [quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) - are you looking for `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()`?

Comment: More context is needed about what it is you are actually trying to test. The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: `What should I replace ??? with?` That depends on what you are actually trying to test.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify your type T in the test method.

Assuming T is string, this should work (in XUnit):

```
mck.Setup(o => o.Method(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<string, bool>>>()))
    .Callback<Expression<Func<string, bool>>>(x => {...});
```